# How to convert Pyspark Row datetime.datetime dataframe to column name DateType with timestamp in DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I m working on NYK Green Taxi Data Jan 2017,I converted string column to Datetype now I can see only in row as alias , How to convert it into dataframe to Show() as table in Pickupdate column and DD-MM-YYYYFormat

```
-- lpep_pickup_datetime: string (nullable = true)

df2 = df.select(to_timestamp(df.lpep_pickup_datetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('pickup_datetime')).collect()

df2
[Row(pickup_datetime=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 1, 15)), Row(pickup_datetime=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 3, 34)), Row(pickup_datetime=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 2)), Row(pickup_datetime=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 1, 40)), Row(pickup_datetime=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 51)), Row(pickup_datetime=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 28))
```

Output should be DD-MM-YYYY format Pickup_datetime Column like 1-1-2017 00:01:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do `collect` which will convert your dataframe into a list of Rows. Just do the `select`, which will return a new dataframe `df2`, and call `show()` on that new dataframe.

```
df2 = df.select(to_timestamp(df.lpep_pickup_datetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('pickup_datetime'))

df2.show()
```